# Where in the database is robots.txt content saved?

Tags: magento2, seo, robots.txt

According to M2 docs.

**You do not have to generate a robots.txt because it generates on demand and stores the contents in the database. It does not create a file, but you can view the content in your browser with the url: /robots.txt**

Where in the database, which table is this information saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information is stored in `core_config_data` can be found in the following row `select * from core_config_data where path = 'design/search_engine_robots/custom_instructions';`